# How do I reorganize a single excel column into multiple dataframe columns based on a shared value?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

If I have an Excel file organized like this:

```
x   a
-----
x1  a1
x2  a2
x3  a3

x   b
-----
x1  b1
x2  b2
x3  b3

x   c
-----
x1  c1
x2  c2
x3  c3
```

What's the easiest way to convert it to a dataframe like this:

```
x   a   b   c
-------------
x1  a1   b1   c1
x2  a2   b2   c2
x3  a3   b3   c3
```

All I can find so far is reading everything in separately, then concatenating dataframes. I feel like there must be a simpler way to do it, but all the results I'm finding are about splitting a column's content in each cell into multiple columns, rather than redistributing a single column and consolidating like I'm looking to do.

Is there a way to use unstack for this?

Comment: You will need to format your data properly, it's hard to interpret

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question here, should be better now

Comment: If that data is in the same excel sheet, I think you WILL have to read everything in separately, then concatenating/merging dataframes.

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark for that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you data is held in a single spreadsheet and the blocks have the same shape and are horizontally aligned, and with arbitrary number of empty rows in-between, you can try this :

```
tmp = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)

s = tmp[0].fillna("NONE"); blocks = s[s.ne(s.shift())].eq("NONE").cumsum()

out = (
    tmp.dropna().join(blocks.rename("idx"))
        .set_index([0, "idx"]).unstack(1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(list(x.iloc[0]), axis=1)
              .rename_axis(x.index[0])).iloc[1:].reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    x   a   b   c
0  x1  a1  b1  c1
1  x2  a2  b2  c2
2  x3  a3  b3  c3
```

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your spreadsheet has 1 (or more) blank rows between each table, and each table has a header. This will be a little messy, just because multiple tables in the same sheet is not a standard format. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1")
df = df[~(df['x'].isnull() | df['x'].isnull().shift(fill_value = False))]
df['col'] = df['a'].str[:1]
df = df.set_index(['x', 'col'])
df = df['a'].unstack().reset_index()
df.columns.name = None
```

The result is:

```
>>> print(df)
    x   a   b   c
0  x1  a1  b1  c1
1  x2  a2  b2  c2
2  x3  a3  b3  c3
```

**To break this down**

First, when we read in the df, the blank rows and the headers of tables after the first will be present as row values:

```
>>> print(df)
      x    a
0    x1   a1
1    x2   a2
2    x3   a3
3   NaN  NaN
4     x    b
5    x1   b1
6    x2   b2
7    x3   b3
8   NaN  NaN
9     x    c
10   x1   c1
11   x2   c2
12   x3   c3
```

Step one is to get rid those extra rows. `df['x'].isnull()` will give us a binary series indicating which rows have a null value for `x`. `df['x'].isnull().shift(fill_value = False)` will shift that down 1 to give us a True value for any row directly below a null row. We specify `fill_value = False` so that it doesn't give us a null in the first row. Then we filter out rows where either of those series is True:

```
 df = df[~(df['x'].isnull() | df['x'].isnull().shift(fill_value = False))]
```

Now we have a slightly cleaner dataframe:

```
>>> print(df)
     x   a
0   x1  a1
1   x2  a2
2   x3  a3
5   x1  b1
6   x2  b2
7   x3  b3
10  x1  c1
11  x2  c2
12  x3  c3
```

In order to use unstack on `a`, we need our index to include `x` and to include an indicator of which rows should end up in which column. Since our column labels are the first character of values, we can do this with `df['a'].str[:1]`. If this is only a feature of your example data you may need to find a different approach for getting this.

```
df['col'] = df['a'].str[:1]
df = df.set_index(['x', 'col'])
```

now we have

```
>>> print(df)
         a
x  col    
x1 a    a1
x2 a    a2
x3 a    a3
x1 b    b1
x2 b    b2
x3 b    b3
x1 c    c1
x2 c    c2
x3 c    c3
```

Finally we unstack, and then `reset_index` to get `x` back out of the index:

```
 df = df['a'].unstack().reset_index()
```

and now we have

```
>>> print(df)
col   x   a   b   c
0    x1  a1  b1  c1
1    x2  a2  b2  c2
2    x3  a3  b3  c3
```

`col` is in the top left because `unstack` makes the name of the level you unstacked in to the name of the column index. You can get rid of this with `df.columns.name = None`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't use unstack but is a little more generalizable

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", "Sheet1")

#split dataframe on null rows
all_dfs = np.split(df, df[df['a'].isnull()].index)

#correct null values and column labels on all dfs after the first
all_dfs_fixed = all_dfs[:1]

for x in all_dfs[1:]:
    x = x.dropna()
    x.columns = x.iloc[0]
    x = x.iloc[1:]
    all_dfs_fixed.append(x)

#merge dataframes on 'x' column
df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on = 'x'), all_dfs_fixed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to take a small powerquery solution.  It is generic as to how many rows are under each set of dotted lines, and can handle mixed quantities in each section

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Split = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Part1", "Part2"}), // split column in to two columns
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Split, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), // add an index
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if  Text.Contains(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Part1],"-") then [Part2] else null otherwise null), //reflect the Part2 for items above the dash
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}), //copy down the column header to all rows
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Part2] <> null),1) , type table [Part1=nullable text, Part2=nullable text, Index=number, Custom=text]}}), //remove null rows and title rows part 1
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Part1", "Part2"}, {"Part1", "Part2"}), //remove null rows and title rows part 2
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded data"[Custom]), "Custom", "Part2") // pivot
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]